# Different action method for the first post and sequential posts

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, http-post

I'm developing an ASP.Net- MVC application and I have the following issue:

I have a view which contains a form and a search button:

After the first click on the search button, I want to go to Action-Method **X** (in the controller).

For the second click, third, forth and so on...I want to go to Action-Method **Y** (in the controller).

What is the best way to achieve that? How can I determine if the current post is the first one after entering the view or is it the second, third...one? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a jquery ajax post

```
 <input id="myhidden" type='hidden' value="first"  />
<input type='button' value="Search" onclick='PostData()' />
//Client Side
function PostData()
{
    if($("#myhidden").val()=='first'){
        AjaxCall(FirstAjaxUrl);
    }
    else{
        AjaxCall(SecondAjaxUrl);
    }
}

function AjaxCall(actionUrl){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: actionUrl,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: {id :1},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(result) {


if($("#myhidden").val()=='first'){
           $("#myhidden").val('second');
        }
        }
    });
}

//AjaxTest Controller
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult FirstAjax(string id)
{

}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SecondAjax(string id)
{

}
```

Comment: Thanks, but what do I write in the if statement when the logic is:
if(first Post){
        AjaxCall(FirstAjaxUrl);
    }
    else{
        AjaxCall(SecondAjaxUrl);
    }

Comment: You can use  from hidden and after first ajax call change it value .I Update my answer